# Very weak solution to parabolic PDE (pointwise a.e. in time with time derivative on test function)

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, parabolic-pde

Consider the parabolic PDE
$$u' + Au = 0$$
as an equality in $L^2(0,T;V^*)$ for some Hilbert space $V$ with $A\colon L^2(0,T;V) \to L^2(0,T;V^*)$ a coercive, bounded linear operator. Here $u'$ is the weak time derivative in the usual sense.

We can write a very weak formulation of the equation as
$$-\int_0^T \langle v'(t), u(t) \rangle + \int_0^T \langle Au(t), v(t) \rangle = 0\tag{1}$$ 
for every $v$ sufficiently smooth with $v(T)=v(0)=0$.

Consider the pointwise a.e. in time equality

$$-\langle v'(t), u(t) \rangle + \langle Au(t), v(t) \rangle = 0.$$

Suppose that solutions and data are smooth.

Is there any theory on such weak formulations and the relation to (1)? Clearly, it implies (1), but there doesn't seem any way to it from (1) (or some form of the original PDE). Is it a useful concept in any way (even for theoretical reasons)?

Comment: I'm not an expert but, since (1) is a linear evolution equation, I think most of the studies on its generalized solutions adopt the concept of *mild solution*, i.e. interpret it as a solution of the following vector-valued integral equation $$ u(T)-u_0=\int\limits_0^T\!\! Au(t)\,\mathrm{d} t.$$ However, it seems to me that the concept of very weak solution is currently adopted in several recent studies on the Navier-Stokes equations (which is however non-linear), as you can see by googling the relevant words.